# Using filter on an object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an object that contains only simple key value pairs and I want to filter out any properties have falsey values. Is this possible using Array.prototype.filter()?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible using Array.prototype.filter()?

Yes, but not directly: You can do it after using `Object.keys` or similar:

```
var arrayOfTruthyValues = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key]);
```

The result is an array of truthy values.

If you want the end result to be an *object*, combining `filter` with `reduce` could do it:

```
var newObj = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => obj[key])
    .reduce((newObj, key) => {
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
        return newObj;
     }, {});
```

That's mostly just using `reduce` as a looping construct (since we never actually change the accumulator value, we just keep returning the same object) which is sometimes considered an "abusage." :-) And it means we could do without the `filter` part and just put an `if` in the `reduce`, but...

---

Note that `Object.keys` only includes an object's *own*, *enumerable* properties. If you want own properties even if they're not enumerable, that would probably be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead.

Comment: We had a small argue and I'm looking forward for your opinion in this case. Who got the right? Who's answer is totally wrong? If you could say something... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356481/how-to-get-the-last-key-of-object-which-has-a-value/42356557